# Jasmine, Ember Views and Runloop: cannot call method 'appendTo' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, jasmine

I'm trying to write a basic test for Ember views, following along here: http://shairez.com/2012/07/ember-js-tdd-how-to-test-your-ember-views/ but I keep getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendTo' of undefined'.

Spec:

```
describe "my view", ->

  myView = null

  beforeEach ->
    myView = Sysys.ActView.create()
    Ember.run ->
      myView.append()


  afterEach ->
    Ember.run ->
      myView.remove()
    myView = null

  it "should be defined", ->
    expect(myView).toBeDefined()

  it "should have a button", ->
    expect(myView.$("button.btn-primary").length).toEqual(1);
```

The error comes comes from [Ember.View.appendTo](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1425-L1434):

```
this.$().appendTo(target)
```

where `target` is the `<body class="ember-application">...</body>`  (as expected) and `this` is `myView`. However, `this.state` is "preRender" and `this.$()` is undefined, which is why the error occurs.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong: the view is getting created but not rendered I think. I have the call to `append()` inside `Ember.run` also, as suggested by the tutorial.

I also noticed that even when I don't run any tests, I still get an uncaught exception -- it's the same thing, except for the ApplicationView. So I'm wondering if I'm initializing everything correctly for the tests. The include files are below (using Rails 3.2 with asset pipeline)

Spec.js.coffee

```
#=require_tree ./
#=require_tree ../../app/assets/javascripts
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs

#= require vendor/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6
#= require vendor/ember-1.0.0-pre.2
#= require vendor/ember-data

#= require_self
#= require sysys
Sysys = Ember.Application.create();
#= require_tree .
```

app/assets/javascripts/sysys.js.coffee:

```
#= require ./store
#= require_tree ./models
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./views
#= require_tree ./helpers
#= require_tree ./templates
#= require_tree ./routes
#= require_self

Sysys.initialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

One can invoke the "this.$()" only after the element was inserted to the DOM. Since you noticed that you're still in state 'preRender', and not yet in DOM ('inDom') the cause might be in a "reRender" (please check call-stack).
This can happen (for example) when using bindAttr and the property that it's bind to was already modified even though the view wasn't inserted to the DOM (*cough* call-stack *cough*).